# Large HTML tag values not show on excel file

Tags: excel, laravel, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

In the laravel project(version **5.8**), we tried two packages("**PHPExcel**" and “**Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel**”) for show the large HTML tag values in excel file.

We follow the below condition to show the HTML values in excel file.

```
$wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML; 
$richText = $wizard->toRichTextObject($stringvalue);
```

**small content HTML** values working fine(bold and underline options working properly)
[image]

But **large content HTML** value is not shown in the excel cell.

Comment: Excel has a character limit of 32,767 characters in a cell - could your $richText exceed this length?

Comment: Hi, @GilesBennett my excel file particular cell 7900 characters only working. The above 7900 characters not working. but my string is not present in you mentioned limit. 

Can you give me any suggestions?